# Precise movements of the cursor on a textfield in ubuntu touch: is there currently a way to do this?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch

In a ubuntuphone (or I assume in general on a Ubuntu Touch GUI on a touch device) how am I supposed to accurately move the cursor while I am editing a line in a textfield?
Tapping is going quite never to be precise enough.